# keytool asking for password to read java certificates ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu-18.04, keystore

I have a fresh installation of ubuntu 18.04. I'm having problems with my builds (e.g. Maven and Gradle) accessing a repository https, the message it shows is:

> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

When I try to access the certificates from my keystore using the following command:

```sh
keytool -list -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

I get prompted with a password, which is not a problem, but if I just press enter without inputting the password It does not show any of the entries.

If I put the password, all the certificates appear normally. What I had to do is add to all my Java applications the following system prop: `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit`

Then everything works normally. What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is the permission on the cacerts right now:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 167K jun  8 11:21 /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

so everyone can read. If I try to use list without a password:

```
keytool -list -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts                                                                             ✔  308  10:27:15 
Enter keystore password:  

*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 0 entries

with the password:keytool -list -keystore /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts                                                                             ✔  310  10:36:33 
Enter keystore password:  
Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 134 entries
```

Comment: Isn't this a normal behaviour ? Your apps should be made aware of the trust-store password someway. In this case you are passing it as a VM argument.

Comment: read should be password free, only write operations should need a password

Answer (score 0):

> read should be password free, only write operations should need a password

You misunderstand the purpose of the password.  The password is (in effect) a decryption key for the keystore.  It protects against unauthorized reads, irrespective of file system permissions.

If you want / need to allow reads *without a password* but protect against writes, you need to use file system permissions for that.  The following Q&A explains how to *remove* the default password:

- [How do I get into a non-password protected Java keystore or change the password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640340)

---

Here's an explanation why a password controlling write (and not read) cannot work.

Suppose that the trusted key store is readable without a password.   A user could then do the following:

- Read the keys in the keystore
- Create a new (empty) keystore
- Write the keys to the new keystore
- Rename the new keystore so that it replaces the old keystore.

This could be done using a custom Java application or (probably) the standard `keytool` utility and the `mv` command.

The only way that you can prevent this is to stop the application (or the user) from replacing the old keystore with the new one *via file system permissions*.  If you can't do that (e.g. because the user has admin-level access) then there is no solution that doesn't have security holes.

Comment: This is the permission on the cacerts right now: ```-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 167K jun  8 11:21 /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

Comment: OK.  So you just need to make sure that you don't run non-trusted (java or other) code as `root` and you are OK.

Comment: Can you check the answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640340/how-do-i-get-into-a-non-password-protected-java-keystore-or-change-the-password

Comment: @Mattos - I don't think that is what the OP is asking.   He is asking for a way to have password-less read, and password-controlled updates.  You can't do that.